# MongoDB aggregation query based on multiple fields with similar values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "001",
    "a" : {
        "b" : {
            "c" : {
                "custId" : "cust1"
            },
            "d" : {
                "custId" : "cust2"
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "002",
    "a" : {
        "b" : {
            "c" : {
                "custId" : "cust1"
            },
            "d" : {
                "custId" : "cust3"
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "003",
    "a" : {
        "b" : {
            "c" : {
                "custId" : null
            },
            "d" : {
                "custId" : "cust2"
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "004",
    "a" : {
        "b" : {
            "c" : {
                "custId" : null
            },
            "d" : {
                "custId" : "cust1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to obtain an aggregation which shows a sorted count of customer ids, ignoring null customer ids, like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "cust1",
    "count" : 3,
    "records" : [ 
        "001", "002", "004"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "cust2",
    "count" : 2,
    "records" : [ 
        "001", "003"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "cust3",
    "count" : 1,
    "records" : [ 
        "002"
    ]
}
```

I think each document needs to be broken down into 1 or 2 customer based arrays than then unwound back into documents, but I have been unable to determine a workable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make an array of `custId`, `$map` to iterate loop of `b` after converting from object to array using `$objectToArray`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `custIds` array
- `$match` to filter none null `custIds` documents
- `$group` by `custIds` and get count of total records and make unique array of `_id` using `$addToset`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      custIds: {
        $map: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$a.b" },
          in: "$$this.v.custId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$custIds" },
  { $match: { custIds: { $ne: null } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$custIds",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      records: { $addToSet: "$_id" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TlF9qQpL2vj)